# Cannot convert string to int in nodejs

Tags: node.js, integer

I cannot properly convert a string to integer in nodejs.

```
   Number('10222366040760949'); 
   Number(10222366040760949);
   parseInt(10222366040760949);
   parseInt(10222366040760949, 10);
```

Always return me **10222366040760948**

The last number change!

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try using BigInt in Javascript
something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt this.

try bigint npm packages in node that may help.

You can try console log `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` to see maximum value
As currently you are crossing max limit of integer handle by Javascript. Your number is too big